# What does $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ mean?

Tags: notation, cryptography, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

What does $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ mean? Is the subscript $2$ a modulo and the superscript $3$ dimensions of each element? I am studying lattice cryptography and set theory and I would like to know the how the LWE works in the simplest way possible.

Here’s what I have found from a research paper:

Comment: Superscripts usually indicate a Cartesian product (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^3$) and subscripts denote modulo $n$.

Comment: i found the research paper on this link:  https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It somewhat depends, but generally $\mathbb{Z}_2$ will mean either the integers mod $2$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) or (less likely in your case) the $2$-adic numbers. The superscript $3$ will generally mean the Cartesian product. Hence,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}_2^3 
&= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \\
&= \{ (x,y,z) \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: OP posted a link to the paper in question in which $s\in \Bbb Z_q^n$ is an $n$-tuple of integers understood mod-$q$.